# Rewrite url with fastcgi in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a working php fastcgi config in nginx. Now I have few requests to handle such as `/X.php` by `/X`, `/Y.php` by `/Y` 
Sounds simple so I wrote the following for testing:

`rewrite   ^/X.php$    /api/v1/stat    last;`

it was caught by php application's 404 handler. here is the nginx error log with rewrite_log on

```
[notice] 15289#0: *759 "^/X.php$" matches "/X.php", client: 10.0.0.12, server: example.com, request: "GET /X.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
[notice] 15289#0: *759 rewritten data: "/api/v1/stat", args: "", client: 10.0.0.12, server: example.com, request: "GET /X.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
[notice] 15289#0: *759 "^/X.php$" does not match "/index.php", client: 10.0.0.12, server: example.com, request: "GET /X.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

If I visit /api/v1/stat directly, it works:

```
[notice] 15125#0: *708 "^/X.php$" does not match "/api/v1/stat", client: 223.104.3.248, server: example.com, request: "GET /api/v1/stat HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
[notice] 15125#0: *708 "^/X.php$" does not match "/index.php", client: 223.104.3.248, server: example.com, request: "GET /api/v1/stat HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Here is my related nginx config:

```
rewrite ^/X.php$    /api/v1/stat last;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ .*\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

Please help me come up a solution. thanks.

**NOTE**

A little background that may help you understand my problem.

It is probably obvious that the following should work and it does:

`rewrite   ^/X.php$    /api/v1/stat    permanent;`

However, I am dealing with some kind of hardware that doesn't understand 301 redirect, so I am trying to do with internal redirect without revealing the redirect.

**UPDATE 1**

The solution I came up is a half only. I got `/X.php` redirect to `/api/v1/stat` fine. However, no parameters can be passed after the redirect. I think `rewrite` will pass along the `$args` but it doesnt work. I am at a loss now..

**UPDATE 2**

Problem solved. though I am still not sure why `$args` is not passing along.

Comment: If it was passed to PHP, then nginx is done; the problem is in your application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks. I suspect that nginx didn't redirect correctly because `/X.php` is redirected to `/api/v1/stat` and failed. but direct visit succeed. I looked further and saw `404 Page Not Found --> X.php`  in log and that does suggest that the redirect failed. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on nginx debug mode and comparing the log between working request with the failed one gives me a clue: the failed request's nginx  `REQUEST_URI` variable is `/X.php` and didn't get updated even after the rewrite. see [nginx doc on variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)

So I need to update `REQUEST_URI` after the rewrite. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869930/how-to-change-request-uri-in-nginx) from SO helps with that.

Here is what works for me:

```
set $request_url $request_uri;
if ($request_uri ~ ^/X.php(.*)$ ) {
    set $request_url   /api/v1/x$1;
    rewrite ^/X.php    /api/v1/x  last;
}

location ~ .*\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_url;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

**UPDATE**

finally, this works with query string in rewrite too.
I added matching query string in the `if` clause and append the matched query string to `request_url`. problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite   ^/X.php$    /api/v1/stat   last;
sends you to "location /"

for example you can use another location for matching this internal redirect:
"/api/v1/stat"

In this location you can pass request to fcgi-backend (or additionally modify it in this location).